# Delete instantiated objects in python

Tags: python

I get different opinions on this topic and have to settle on one idea.

Is this useful to do in python? Because I read that Python objects are automatically destroyed, but for safety reasons `del` should be  explicitly called to delete instantiated objected.

```
class A:            
    def __init__(self):  
        print("A")  

class B:            
    def __init__(self):  
        print("B")  
    
class base:         
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()
        self._b = B()

    def __del__(self):
        del self._a
        del self._b

_base = base()
del _base
```

In other documents I have read that the `context manager` or `CPython` can be used for this purpose, but I don't know how or whether it is necessary.

Comment: So you've answered your own question? But yea `del` is enough

Comment: Is *what exactly* useful to do? To define a `__del__` method of a class, or to use a `del` statement?

Comment: to call `del` to delete objects